TypeScript type-level programming: check that an object has at least two fields
I'm trying to do generic programming with a library that requires input objects to have at least two fields (whatever their names are). I'd like to create a utility type that tests for this.
type A = ObjectWithAtLeastTwoFields<{ a: 0, b: 1 }> // { a: 0, b: 1 }
type B = ObjectWithAtLeastTwoFields<{ a: 0 }> // never
type C = ObjectWithAtLeastTwoFields<{}> // never


Why do you want this? It’s possible to do but what is the use case? I’m worried I’ll write up such a type function and you’ll say it doesn’t meet an underlying need.

Like, I threw this together, but I don't know if it actually meets whatever your use case is. There are always edge cases (e.g., index signatures, optional properties, unions of objects, arrays, etc etc ect).  Does my approach work for you? If so I could write an answer. If not, please [edit] to make your needs clear.

Again, this approach is perfectly acceptable in terms of TS supportability (unlike the answer below which needlessly orders the keys before counting them). I don't know if it is what you want, but I'm happy to write it up. Could you comment on whether it works for your use case? If I don't hear back I'll probably write up the answer anyway, since messing with key order really isn't the way someone should approach this and I don't want that to be the only answer here.

Essentially we want to check whether keyof X is at least 2 in length. Now, keyof X will give you a union of all possible fields like A | B | .... You cannot iterate the union values directly, but there is a scary way to turn a union into a tuple, at which point you can get its length.

Here is the relevant answer by jcalz: How to transform union type to tuple type
It comes with a disclaimer:

DISCLAIMER: DON'T DO THIS!! If someone tells you to use the code they found in this answer to do anything except demonstrate why this is a bad idea, RUN AWAY!!

But let's actually understand why this is a bad idea. Maybe the more constrained problem as here makes this method OK?
Let's go over the reasons cited by jcalz:



You can't rely on the ordering of a union type.

This is irrelevant for merely counting the number of members, so OK so far.



You might not be happy with what the compiler considers a union and when it collapses or expands.

This actually does affect our use case since somebody might use ObjectWithAtLeastTwoFields on a type without statically-known fields. For example, const x: Record<string, number> = {a: 1, b: 2} has at least two fields, but keyof (typeof x) = string so our code would only find one "field" and fail.


For the same reason, no other method could ever reliably work with a generic object. If the set of all field names is not statically available or lost at some point by e.g. unifying literals with a type, there is simply insufficient information for this predicate to work.

If you understand all the risks and want to do this anyway, here is some code in the typescript playground.

You don’t need to order the keys to make sure there’s at least two of them.  I’m not sure why someone wants to make such a check, but this code does it without doing any weird union ordering stuff.

This is hilarious and solves more than one of my problems. Thanks!
